# How to display image in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, xampp

I want to display image form view

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('images/login.jpg'); ?> " width="90" height="40" />
```

But it doesn't work.
When I write

```
<img src="images/login.jpg " width="90" height="40" />
```

It show in browser but not show in localhost

Does the problem in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /helloworld/

    # Disable rewrite for valid directory/files    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

    #map all request urls to a specific controller method
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/{controller}/{method}/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

please anyone help me

Comment: How does it not work? It simply doesn't show? any errors you get?

Comment: check through inspect element whether image is loading there or not

Comment: It is loading but the image doesn't display

Comment: so your path might be the issue,in the inspect element is the path shown correct?

Comment: When i do this <img src="images/login.jpg " width="90" height="40" />  it work in inspect mode and show but not show in localhost

Answer (score 0):

If you just want access without "index.php" in your htaccsess file should be like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /helloworld/

    # Disable rewrite for valid directory/files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    #map all request urls to a specific controller method
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And the images folder must be in the root of your project. 
I hope my answer can help you :D

Comment: My image in  images folder in my project in the views folder

Comment: You can load image in view folder if you store it in view folder by base url, i think in this case you have to use static url, like:
<img src="'images/login.jpg'" />
Because when you use base_url("'images/login.jpg'"), image src url is "http:localhost/images/login.jpg" and it must be in images folder in root.

Answer (score 0):

This method regardless of `.htaccess` file and put `index.php`:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('index.php/images/login.jpg'); ?> " width="90" height="40" />
```

But if you still want to use `.htaccess` file then replace all codes `.htaccess` file with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Then you can access without `index.php`

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('images/login.jpg'); ?> " width="90" height="40" />
```

Comment: I try the two solution but the image doesn't display

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/login.jpg" width="90" height="40" />
```

as well as in `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

and your image should be place one

```
application
images
    login.jpg
system
index.php
```

Comment: remove it. just keep empty

Comment: @A.Nabil what happen?

Comment: I removed it but also image doesn't displayed

Comment: @A.Nabil just check weather the image does not have JPG extension instead of jpg. In linux system the case matters.

Comment: view/myproject/images/login.jpg   I loaded it from  Home_view in myproject

Comment: In folder controller   log_c      in view   my project folder  in it images folder       and home_view.php  in images  login.jpg image                                                  in   home_view.php this code                                                                                           <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/login.jpg'); ?> " width="90" height="40" />

Comment: there is no difernce in both of code . Check your page source.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any class name related with advertisement ??
if yes ad block extension of browsers tends to hide the images, faced similar problems in my project too just disable the extension for the test or change the class name.

Just a guess. Hope it helps you.

Comment: you should ask question as comment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to import url helper on your controller constructor.

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

Comment: I loaded the helper url